# Angular: components height to screen only

Tags: html, css, angular

How can I set in Angular all components max-height and max-width to fit screen size? I don't want setting sizes to 100% from html all the way to the component is not what I'm looking for, I don't want nested components to exceed the screen size

Answer (score 0):

maybe this work:

```
*{
    max-width: 100vw; // view width
    max-height: 100vh; // view height
}
```

`vh` and `vw` are the viewport size

Answer (score 0):

May be this css can fixed your problem (This is responsive from everywhere) please follow this link https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

```
* {
    margin: 0 ;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.box{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Html Goes here

```
<body>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</body>
```